# Hiding facebook app_id in Android Application

Tags: android, facebook, hide, app-id

I am wondering if it's possible to hide the `Facebook` app id for my application? The `apk` can be decoded with special tools like `apktool` and I don't want my `Facebook` app id or other private information to be visible in the code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this; an App ID is basically public information and is included in the dialogs the user sees when authorising the desktop/web (if applicable) version of the app. It will be also visible to the user in their privacy settings after they authorise your app, visible when they search for your app, etc.

If you're referring to your App Secret, under **no** circumstances should this be distributed with your client code, if you're making API calls which need the App Secret you should make these calls from a server and set up a communication path between your client app and this server - the app secret should never be passed over this path as with it users could make API calls on behalf of the app

Answer (score 0):

you could use proguard to obfuscate your code and as an extra measure you could compose your appid string in a for to concatenate characters

Answer (score 0):

You could load that ID from a server at app-start. I assume you need INTERNET permission for FB anyway ..